# BVH has no root motion

Tags: rigging, motion-capture

I have recorded motion capture using Motive and am now trying to use the motion capture for a blender animation. The BVH file has the hips set as a root bone with no key frames, so the character walks in place or when it's supposed to jump the hips don't translate or move at all. Is there a way to have it have the keyframes and animations I captured? The FBX versions of the files don't seem to have this problem, so I am confused.

Thanks in advance.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5yQhbjDIKrFWG1TOE1jYnBxejQ/view?usp=sharing[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5yQhbjDIKrFWG1TOE1jYnBxejQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please provide your bvh file to have a look

Answer (score 1):

The BVH itself doesn't contain any animation for the root joint `__0`. The root name doesn't match the naming of the other joints (I would have expected `Ryan_Hips`). This is a problem with your exporter, not with Blender.

Comment: So did we probably export it wrong from Motive? The FBX does not have this problem with a root bone and is able to move around. I have to tried to export the FBX as a BVH and also exported it as a BVH straight from Motive.

Comment: Yes, it's a problem with the export.